# Kotlin: Conditionally change radio button color

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing a multiple choice quiz in kotlin. When the user submits an answer, I want the radio button for the correct answer to be green and the radio button for the selected answer (if incorrect) to be red. The default radio button settings for when the user selects an answers (before submitting) are to remain unchanged.

Currently, I can set the radio button for the correct answer to green, but can't figure out red. After submitting the answer and going to the next question, the green radio button does not clear. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Radio for correct option

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
            <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="#0E6E11"/>
            <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Radio for incorrect option

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
            <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
            <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Quiz code

```
class QuestionsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var mCurrentPosition:Int = 1
    private var mQuestionsList:ArrayList<Questions>? = null
    private var mSelectedOptionPosition:Int = 0
    private var mCorrectAnswers: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions)
        mQuestionsList = Constants.getQuestions()
        setQuestion()
        radio_button1.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button2.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button3.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button4.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun setQuestion() {
        val question = mQuestionsList!![mCurrentPosition-1]
        defaultOptionsView()
        if(mCurrentPosition == mQuestionsList!!.size){
            btn_submit.text = "FINISH"
        }else{
            btn_submit.text = "SUBMIT"
        }
        progressBar.progress = mCurrentPosition
        tv_progress.text = "$mCurrentPosition" + "/" + progressBar.max
        tv_question.text = question !!.question
        radio_button1.text = question.option1
        radio_button2.text = question.option2
        radio_button3.text = question.option3
        radio_button4.text = question.option4
    }

    private fun defaultOptionsView(){
        val options = ArrayList<TextView>()
        options.add(0, radio_button1)
        options.add(1, radio_button2)
        options.add(2, radio_button3)
        options.add(3, radio_button4)

        for (option in options){
            option.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
            option.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT
            option.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.radio_button1 ->{
                selectedOptionView(radio_button1, 1)
            }
            R.id.radio_button2 ->{
                selectedOptionView(radio_button2, 2)
            }
            R.id.radio_button3 ->{
                selectedOptionView(radio_button3, 3)
            }
            R.id.radio_button4 ->{
                selectedOptionView(radio_button4, 4)
            }
            R.id.btn_submit ->{
                if(mSelectedOptionPosition == 0){
                    if (radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId == -1 && btn_submit.isPressed && btn_submit.text == "SUBMIT") {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        radio_group.clearCheck()
                        mCurrentPosition++
                    }
                    when{
                        mCurrentPosition <= mQuestionsList!!.size ->{
                            setQuestion()
                        }else ->{
                            val intent = Intent(this, ResultsActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.TOTAL_CORRECT, mCorrectAnswers)
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.TOTAL_OPP, mQuestionsList!!.size)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    val question = mQuestionsList?.get(mCurrentPosition -1)
                    if(question!!.correctAnswer !=mSelectedOptionPosition) {
                        answerView(mSelectedOptionPosition, R.drawable.incorrect_option_border_bg)

                    }else{
                        mCorrectAnswers++
                    }
                    answerView(question.correctAnswer, R.drawable.correct_option_border)
                    if(mCurrentPosition == mQuestionsList!!.size){
                        btn_submit.text="FINISH"
                    }else{
                        btn_submit.text = "NEXT QUESTION"
                    }
                    mSelectedOptionPosition = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun answerView(answer: Int, drawableView: Int) {
        when(answer){
            1 ->{
                radio_button1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableView)
                radio_button1.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.correct_option_radio)
            }
            2 ->{
               radio_button2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableView)
                radio_button2.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.correct_option_radio)
            }
            3 ->{
                radio_button3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableView)
                radio_button3.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.correct_option_radio)
            }
            4 ->{
                radio_button4.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableView)
                radio_button4.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.correct_option_radio)
            }
        }
    }

    private  fun selectedOptionView(tv: TextView, selectedOptionNum: Int) {
        defaultOptionsView()
        mSelectedOptionPosition = selectedOptionNum
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
        tv.setTypeface(tv.typeface, Typeface.BOLD)
        tv.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.selected_option_border_bg)
    }
}
```